# PM2 offline install on Window Server?

Tags: windows, npm, offline, pm2

Production server is not allowed to internet. It is in a private network.

It is Window 2016 Server.

How can I install pm2 on Windows without internet?

I've tried these.

npm pack pm2   (pc with network)

npm i -g pm2-4.2.1.tgz  (server offline)

But it didn't work.

Do you know how to install pm2 on Windows offline??

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me:

1. Install pm2 globally on your local machine with internet by running the command below:

   `> npm install pm2 -g`

2. After successful installation of the above, A new folder named pm2 will be created in the below path in your local machine. Copy this folder and place this exactly in the same path on your server which does not have internet.

   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

3. Some of the files with files names starting with 'pm2' will be created in the below path on your local machine. Copy these files as well and place them exactly in the same path on your server.

   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

4. Make sure this path `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` is added to your environment variables PATH.

5. Once the above steps are done. Open a new command prompt and run the command `pm2` and now it will be recognized and working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the package from here - https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/releases
2. This package doesn't contain any node_modules. So you have install the dependencies by using ***npm i*** command. Before that you have to extract and run this command inside the downloaded folder.
3. After Install the dependencies package. You have to move the folder into your Windows server.
4. Inside the PM2 package folder you can see the bin folder. Visit the location inside by using command prompt.
5. Then run the pm2 command whatever you want. That's all.

[image]

Comment: Thank you~. I cann't run MINGW64. Should I install "MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows" ??

Comment: What do you mean MINGW 64?

Comment: You said, "run this comand"   -   I meant the screen you captured.   "2. This package doesn't contain any node_modules. So you have install the dependencies by using npm i command. Before that you have to extract and run this command inside the downloaded folder."

Comment: Download and extract the package, Then run npm -i from extracted folder.

Comment: Could you check what I did?
(this computer with online)
1. download pm2-4.2.1.zip and  extract file.
2.  move to extracted folder   (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pm2-4.2.1)
3.  in cmd

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pm2-4.2.1>npm i